# How to test es6 module that imports jquery with jsdom

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, babeljs, jsdom

I am struggling to get mocha, jsdom, es6 modules with babel to play nice with jquery.

Here's a module

```
// lib/dom.js
import $ from 'jquery';

const node = (tag)=> $(`<${tag} />`)

export {
  node
}
```

Here's a test

```
// test/dom.js
import assert from 'assert';
import { node } from '../src/lib/dom';

describe('node(tag)', ()=> {
  it('should return a Node', ()=> {
    let img = node('img');
    assert(img.nodeName === 'IMG');
  });
});
```

Here's the jsdom setup

```
// test/_setup.js
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = document.parentWindow;
```

The script to run

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive
```

What do I need to change to allow jsdom to load jquery so that dom.js can load the jquery module without getting the error:

Error: jQuery requires a window with a document

Here's the full source https://github.com/markbrown4/test-simple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it, test/_setup.js needed the following:

```
global.document = require('jsdom').jsdom('<html></html>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

document.parentWindow is deprecated from jsdom.

Comment: I've tried this, but `global.$` seems to be an object instead of a function... any idea why?

Comment: In this case you are not using es6 module import

Answer (score 3):

I think this will be a more suitable example since in this case I'm using es6 import:

```js
    import {JSDOM} from 'jsdom';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';

    const dom = new JSDOM(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <td> student</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    `);

    // if you are using TypeScript you will need to ignore next line
    // @ts-ignore
    global.window = dom.window;
    // @ts-ignore
    global.document = dom.window.document;

   // And now you can access JSDOM document from Jquery
   $('#table').html(); // ?
```

Comment: I needed to ES6 import jsdom - this worked thanks! (I'm not using jQuery):  import {JSDOM} from 'jsdom'; const dom = new JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello</p>");